Расположение последнего символа в блоке с текстом
Есть блок, ширина может разной, как и текст в нем.


    .bl {
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      word-break: break-word;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
    div > div {
       position: absolute;
       left:10px;
       color:red;
       bottom: 0px;
    }
<div class='bl'>
  Text Text Text Text Text
  Text Text Text Text
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
  Text Text Text
  <div>Еще</div>
</div>



